# Rails 5 Heroku set port

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Привет. Необходимо запустить проект на фиксированном порту в heroku web:
`rails server -p 3000 -e production` - этот код приводит к ошибке:

> Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

Как это исправить?

Comment: А чем вам не угодил порт в `$PORT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Инфраструктура Heroku у web-машинок вам не позволит пользоваться никакими портами, кроме того, что указан в `$PORT`, запросы будут приходить именно на него, с роутера Heroku.

Там стоит обратный прокси на портах 80 и 443, который занимается балансировкой и SSL, чтобы вам не надо было это делать самостоятельно.

Скорее всего, вам нужно выкинуть `Procfile` совсем и пользоваться тем, что Heroku добавляет по умолчанию. Но если хотите починить именно вашу команду, то это:

```
rails server -p $PORT -e production
```

Comment: Спасибі я вже це зрозумів в принципі можна заставити heroku пахати під себе але тоді вискакують проблеми з node я вирішив це.Спасибі

Comment: @YaroslavMaluk половину не понял, но пожалуйста :)